# How do I deepen my voice (I'm a female) to sound like a man in a video for a school project?

Tags: filters, audio, pitch, voice

Some extra info. that I think might help or make things clearer:

- The video has several other people in it also talking (I don't want
  to change their voices).
- I have some experience in editing videos(nothing major I've only ever used 
  Flimora and Imovie)but I've never had to edit someone's voice.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from first principles i.e devising your own signal processing algorithm, or using existing software? Note that software requests are off-topic on this SE. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I would be more inclined to believe that you are looking for an "off-the-shelf" way of doing this and therefore, it is more likely that your question is indeed "off-topic". But, more generally, you can have a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_frequency) for the differences in pitch and then try to [adjust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time_stretching_and_pitch_scaling) the voice channel.[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org) has the functionality to do this. But this assumes one single person talking. Person specific pitch shifting is a very complex task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know some audio software that does a good job:

- Audacity (free software) - effect -> change pitch (set the pitch to down, lower down the semi-tones and the percent change)
- Adobe Audition (paid software) - there is a plugin called pitch shifter (lower down a little bit the semi-tones and cents)

Both are audio software which means you will need to export your audio from the video clip and because there are other people talking in the video you will need to select the parts only were you are talking and then apply the effect.

Comment: there is another parameter to look into besides the **pitch shift** amount is the **formant shift** amount.  (*formants* are the resonant frequencies of the vocal cavity.)  i dunno what current software has this control, but PurePitch (a product i worked on) used to have this.  a hardware device that has this is the [Roland VT-3 Voice Transformer](https://www.roland.com/global/products/vt-3/), but this might also be an old product.  so i do not know who has a software product that has independent control on pitch shift and formant shift, but the OP may need them both to change gender.

Comment: Thank you for this information, however I just googled PurePitch to try it out but the search results only gave me information about the PurePitch White Lab (a chemistry experiment that is revolutionizing the art of fermentation). Do you by any chance have something else I could use?

Comment: You can try Ocenaudio but Audacity offers more as a free software.